# SQL Valor maximo de uma outra tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou fazendo um projeto do curso e travei no ultimo passo e gostaria de uma ajudinha de vocês..

O projeto é um banco de dados em SQL com "leasing" (contrato para "aluguel" de carros.)

As tabelas que importam aqui e os valores são: (existem mais valores, mas creio que não importem..)

```
Tabela 1: Vehicles
PK VehicleID
FK ModelID
FK TypeID
FK ColorID

Tabela 2: Model
PK ModelID
Model

Tabela 3: VehicleType
PK TypeID
VehicleType

Tabela 4: Color
PK ColorID
Color

Tabela 5: Leases
PK LeaseID
FK VehicleID
FK TermID

Tabela 6: LeaseTerms
PK TermID
MaximumKM (maximo de kilometros que o contratante pode andar durante o período.
```

O problema é que no projeto, pede para que eu faça um script que mostre uma lista dos veículos (VehicleID) com as informações de VehicleID, Model(pego através do ModelID), VehicleType(pego através do TypeID), Color(pego através do ColorID) e o maior MaximumKM com o qual esse veículo já foi "alugado"..

Por exemplo, o Cliente X alugou o veículo 1 com MaximumKM de 100.000Km.
O Cliente Y alugou o veículo 1 com MaximumKM de 120.000Km.

No SELECT, só pode aparecer 1 linha para cada veículo e com o valor máximo do MaximumKM que ele já foi alugado, ou seja:

VehicleID = 1, VehicleType = 'SUV', Model = 'Explorer', Color = 'Blue', MaximumKM = 120.000. O valor mais baixo de 100.000Km é ignorado.

Estou desde ontem pesquisando e tentando vários JOINs sem sucesso, porque esse é o primeiro contato que estou tendo com SQL! Se alguém puder ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu caso você pode utilizar uma `subquery` para obter o resultado desejado:

```
SELECT v.*,
       (SELECT MAX(lt.MaximumKM)
          FROM Leases l
               INNER JOIN LeaseTerms lt ON lt.TermID = l.TermID
         WHERE l.VehicleID = v.VehicleID)
  FROM Vehicles v
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Deu certo! Parece ser uma coisa tão simples e eu querendo complicar

Answer (score 3):

Rafael a instrução seria a seguinte:

```
Select VehicleID,  
       MAX(LeaseTerms.MaximumKM) 
from Leases
JOIN LeaseTerms on (Leases.TermID = LeaseTerms.termID) 
GROUP BY VehicleID
```

Nesse exemplo utilizei uma tabela com os seguinte dados:

Tabela de Leases
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela de LeaseTerms
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com esses dados o resultado da query será:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vinculando os dados com a tabela de **Vehicles**, veja que basta só adicionar um novo **JOIN**

```
Select Leases.VehicleID, 
       MAX(LeaseTerms.MaximumKM), 
       Vehicles.Model, 
       Vehicles.Type,
       Vehicles.Model 
from Leases 
JOIN LeaseTerms on (Leases.TermID = LeaseTerms.termID) 
JOIN Vehicles on (Leases.VehicleID = Vehicles.VehicleID)
GROUP BY VehicleID
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, Clayton!!
Mas acho que preciso fazer o SELECT FROM Vehicles, porque tenho que mostrar alguns valores como tipo do carro, modelo e etc que estão guardados nas suas respectivas tabelas com FKs na tabela Vehicles!

Vou editar minha pergunta pra deixar isso mais claro. Mas obrigado pela resposta!!

Comment: Se quiser mostrar dados do carro precisa sim, nesse caso basta adicionar mais um JOIN para unir a tabela de veiculos. Eu alterei a resposta complementando esse caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Clayton!! Projeto finalizado! Agora vou estudar mais sobre JOIN e subquery pra tentar aprender melhor